# Trying to run the python app in flask but it's not running?

Tags: python, opencv, flask, machine-learning, mediapipe

Trying to run the  python app in flask but it's not running ?? and not able to understand the problem that are occuring in it.
Trying to run the  python app in flask but it's not running ?? and not able to understand the problem that are occuring in itTrying to run the  python app in flask but it's not running ?? and not able to understand the problem that are occuring in it

```
from flask import Flask
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mediapipe as mp


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/posedetection", methods =['GET'])
def checkpos():
    mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
    mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose
    
    
    def calculate_angle(a,b,c):
        
        a = np.array(a) # First
        b = np.array(b) # Mid
        c = np.array(c) # End
        
        radians = np.arctan2(c[1]-b[1], c[0]-b[0]) - np.arctan2(a[1]-b[1], a[0]-b[0])
        angle = np.abs(radians*180.0/np.pi)
        
        if angle >180.0:
            angle = 360-angle
        return angle
    
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    
    # Curl counter variables
    counter = 0
    stage = None
    
    
    ## Setup mediapipe instance
    with mp_pose.Pose(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as pose:
        
        while cap.isOpened():
            
            
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            
            # Recolor image to RGB
            image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            image.flags.writeable = False
            
            # Make detection
            results = pose.process(image)
            
            # Recolor back to BGR
            image.flags.writeable = True
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
            
            # Extract landmarks
            try:
                
                
                landmarks = results.pose_landmarks.landmark
                
                # Get coordinates
                l_shoulder = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER.value].x,landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER.value].y]
                l_elbow = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ELBOW.value].x,landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ELBOW.value].y]
                l_wrist = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_WRIST.value].x,landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_WRIST.value].y]
                l_hip   = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_HIP.value].x,landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_HIP.value].y]
                
                r_shoulder = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_SHOULDER.value].x,landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_SHOULDER.value].y]
                r_elbow = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_ELBOW.value].x,landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_ELBOW.value].y]
                r_wrist = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_WRIST.value].x,landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_WRIST.value].y]
                r_hip   = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_HIP.value].x,landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_HIP.value].y]
                
                      
                
                
                # Calculate angle
                angle = calculate_angle(l_shoulder, l_elbow, l_wrist)
                angle1= calculate_angle(l_hip, l_shoulder, l_elbow)
                angle2= calculate_angle(r_shoulder, r_elbow, r_wrist)
                angle3= calculate_angle(r_hip, r_shoulder, r_elbow)
                
                
                # Visualize angle
                cv2.putText(image, str(angle), 
                            tuple(np.multiply(l_elbow, [640, 480]).astype(int)), 
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA
                                )
                
                
                
                cv2.putText(image, str(angle2), 
                           tuple(np.multiply(r_elbow, [640, 480]).astype(int)), 
                           cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA
                                )
            
            
            
        
                # Curl counter logic
                #LEFT SIDE
            
                if (angle>150 and angle2>150) and (angle3<30 and angle1<30) :
                    
                    stage = "down"
                
                if (angle<50 and angle2<50) and (angle3<30 and angle1<30) and stage=='down' :
                    
                
                    stage= "up"
                    counter +=1
                    print(counter)
                
                if angle1>30 or angle3>30:
                    
                    stage="reduce gap between shoulder"
                
            
        
              
            
            except:
                
                pass 
            
            # Render curl counter
            # LEFT Setup status box
            cv2.rectangle(image, (0,0), (225,73), (245,117,16), -1)
        
            # LEFT Rep data
            cv2.putText(image, 'REPS', (0,12), 
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0,0,0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(image, str(counter), 
                    (10,60), 
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255,255,255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            
            # LEFT Stage data
            cv2.putText(image, 'STAGE', (120,12), 
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0,0,0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(image, stage, 
                    (120,60), 
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255,255,255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            
            
            
            
            
            # Render detections
            mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.pose_landmarks, mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
                                mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,117,66), thickness=2, circle_radius=2), 
                                mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,66,230), thickness=2, circle_radius=2) 
                                 )               
        
            cv2.imshow('Mediapipe Feed', image)

            if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                
                break
        
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()  
        
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

[The output which i get is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMOXH.png)

Comment: some of the code has not fallen into the code part of the question. Please edit the otherwise good question to contain this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing GET to POST in `@app.route("/posedetection", methods =['GET'])` and give some more details about the problem you are facing.

Comment: i have done the changes in the question and also added the output that i got everytime. So please look into it